# Java regex to test contains any letter but only 3 spaces between strings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to form regex to validate a string pattern "part1 atmost-2-words part2". The part1 and part2 are fixed strings and in between that it can contain any letters but at most 3 spaces.

Example: part1=This is, part2=error

This is intermittent system error - **Valid**

This is a intermittent system error - **Invalid**

This is error - **Valid**

I have to do this using regex alone. Whether this can be done using regex alone?

Comment: Yes, but where are you stuck? Please share the pattern you have tried and explain what does not work.

Comment: Based on the content of the post - don't you mean four spaces (atleast in regards to making the string valid or invalid..)? You might want to use similar to this regexp:  `^[\w]+(\s[\w]+){0,4}$` It will validate that a maximum of four spaces can exists within any string - should validate your requirements..

Comment: I am trying to form a pattern like "This is [\\w*\\s{0,3}] error". This is to pass to existing utility that validates the strings for given pattern and takes actions based on the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the your statement, The below regex will do the work

```
This is( \w+\s*\w*)? error
```

Since `This is` and `error` are fixed with atmost 2 patterns in between. this should work fine.

Tried with regex101 and works fine, check it out https://regex101.com/r/mQ0uEM/1

Comment: Thanks that worked. I have slightly modified it as below to match all my cases (.*?This is(\\s??\\w*){0,4}error){1}?.*?

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
   static String  P1 = "This is";
   static String  P2 = "error";
   static Pattern p  = Pattern.compile( P1 + "\\W+(\\w+\\W+){0,2}" + P2 );

   static void test( String sentence ) {
      final Matcher m = p.matcher( sentence );
      if( m.matches()) {
         System.out.printf("%s - Valid\n", sentence );
      }
      else {
         System.out.printf("%s - Invalid\n", sentence );
      }
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      test( "This is intermittent system error" );
      test( "This is a intermittent system error" );
      test( "This is error" );
   }
```

The output:

```
This is intermittent system error - Valid
This is a intermittent system error - Invalid
This is error - Valid
```

Explanation:

- \W+ is a non-word character: [^\w], one or more
- \w+ is a word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9], one or more
- {0,2} is none, one or two and no more

[The reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)